Ошибка при создании соединения в Oracle Sql Developer
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно нажать или сделать, чтобы убрать эту ошибку и нормально создать базу данных? 

Ошибка вам говорит, что такой БД(SID = xe) на указанном хосте нет. И данный инструмент предназначен для работы с уже созданной БД, а не для ее создания. Создание БД делается другими инструментами
